# Facebook app working on serve side, not working as a "App on Facebook"

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm doing a facebook app and it works fine on my server and url, when i try to integrate it as a "App on Facebook" it fails to load or login after logout. I believe that the scope for permissions is giving some problems.

The url for the server: http://veritas.betamass.com

The url for the "App on Facebook" side: https://apps.facebook.com/orientacionveritas/

**Note that if you login successfully on the server the you will be able to see the "App on Favcebook, if not you will get a nothing.**

The code that makes the connection to facebook:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    //Application Configurations
    $app_id     = "148133482012457";
    $app_secret = "24d0088e17c1dcb33ac6bb424a5d2a5c";
    $site_url   = "http://veritas.betamass.com/";

    try{
        include_once "src/facebook.php";
    }catch(Exception $e){
        error_log($e);
    }
    // Create our application instance
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     => $app_id,
        'secret'    => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true,
        ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

    // We may or may not have this data based 
    // on whether the user is logged in.
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
    // the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don�t know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
    //print_r($user);
    if($user){
        // Get logout URL

        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    }else{
        // Get login URL
        $params = array(
        'scope' => 'read_stream, publish_stream, email, user_about_me, user_hometown, user_education_history, user_interests',
        'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
        );
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

        /*$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'read_stream, publish_stream, email, user_about_me, user_hometown, user_education_history',
            'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
            ));*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't exist or doesn't have a session, you need to make them login first. Your code doesn't take this into account.

Try redirecting the user to `$facebook->getLoginUrl()` if the session / `$facebook->getUser()` returns `false`.